# Setting CircularImageView border color programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I am using the [CircularImageView](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) library. I have a `CircularImageView` in my `ViewHolder`, and I want to change its border color on click.

My `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ThumbnailAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ... //getting the relevant user from dataset and other irrelevant stuff

        if(selectedUsers.size() == 0 || selectedUsers.contains(user)) {
            holder.thumbnail.setBorderColor(R.color.selected);
        } else {
            holder.thumbnail.setBorderColor(R.color.not_selected);
        }

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (selectedUsers.contains(user)) {
                    selectedUsers.remove(user);
                } else {
                    selectedUsers.add(user);
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```

The weird thing is that the first coloring works (the border color is indeed not the one predefined in the xml), but any further change does not affect the view (though the event is called and the value is changed). I tried to change also the drawable to eliminate a `RecyclerView`-related problem, and it works as expected.

Am I doing anything wrong? Maybe there's a bug in the library (if so, I couldn't find it)? Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:** More adapter code:

```
public ThumbnailAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, parent, false);
        return new ThumbnailAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircularImageView thumbnail;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            thumbnail = (CircularImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_thumbnail);
        }
    }

private List<User> mDataSet;
private List<User> selectedUsers;

public ThumbnailAdapter(List<User> dataSet) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        selectedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Setting the adapter:

```
        mAdapter = new ThumbnailAdapter(users);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: could you post the rest of the adapter code ? most importantly the onCreateViewHolder and also the VH code

Comment: @goldenb Added. I dismissed irrelevant code like communicating with the parent activity.

Comment: could you post the 
"  ... //getting the relevant user from dataset and other irrelevant stuff" part?

Comment: I am assuming that your LayoutManager can be trusted and its "onItemsChanged()" method is working well  (it is called when the adapters' notifyDataSetChanged() is called) - you are not using a CustomLayout manager right?

Comment: how you are getting value into **user** while adding selectedUsers.add(user);

Comment: @goldenb I have a list of Users which I receive in adapter's constructor. The list does not change during the app's lifespan, and I use `position` parameter to get the relevant user. I'm using a standard `LinearLayoutManager`.

Comment: @RahulKhurana I added the code to the question.

Comment: @NeriaNachum i haven't seen what is ask from your side.

Comment: I want to apply `setBorderColor()`. Currently, the method is called but for some reason the UI is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, try this:

[image]

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder mholder, int position) {

        final User user = mList.get(position);


        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) mholder;

        if(selectedUsers.size() == 0 || selectedUsers.contains(user))
        {
            //holder.thumbnail.setBorderColor(Color.GREEN);

            setBorder(holder.thumbnail, true);
        } else {
            //holder.thumbnail.setBorderColor(Color.RED);
            setBorder(holder.thumbnail, false);

        }

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (selectedUsers.contains(user)) {
                    selectedUsers.remove(user);
                } else {
                    selectedUsers.add(user);
                }

                //notifyItemChanged(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public void setBorder(CircularImageView circularImageView, boolean selected) {

        // Set Border
        if(selected) {
            circularImageView.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            circularImageView.setBorderWidth(50);
            circularImageView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        }
        else
        {
            circularImageView.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            circularImageView.setBorderWidth(50);
            circularImageView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        }
// Add Shadow with default param
        //circularImageView.addShadow();
// or with custom param
        //circularImageView.setShadowRadius(1);
        //circularImageView.setShadowColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Something else you should do for performance improvement: look inside your `View.OnClickListener()` switch the `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will force a complete full layout on the `LayoutManager` for the precision method `notifyItemChanged(position);` which will perform the task you want without redrawing everything

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: @NeriaNachum have you been able to solve your problem?  let me know if this helped =)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works (I honestly have no idea why my original code didn't work, as it seems pretty similar). Regarding notifying, I need to notify the whole dataset since all items are affected when changing from 1 selection to 0 (or 0 to 1).

Comment: yes your initial code seemed ok that's why I tested it with a standard view first (standard ImageView in this case) and it worked, so your adapter code was OK as I thought. Then I was forced to test the specific library you wanted, and got the same result. I noticed in the github project page that they are very specific on how we should set up the View and voila, using their setup methods works.
Bottom line, in my work I make no assumptions when using code I haven't personally tested x'D 
cheers mate